# Cannot connect to Wifi Network

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my system. Initially Wi-fi successfully connected  to a networ. 
E.g.: "Mario"

After a while, I deleted "Mario" from edit connections. Then I tried to connect to the same Wi-fi again but it's not working. Why? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Should appear in network manager as asual even though you edited it. Could you [edit] your post with a screenshot of your network manager (something like this: https://community.linuxmint.com/img/screenshots/network-manager-gnome.png). Please edit your post with the output of sudo 'lshw -c network' and 'ifconfig -a' and 'rfkill list'

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 output is kernel driver in use : RTL8723BE